# Can't upload files in Phabricator

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phabricator

This is on a private server. I have one outstanding issue from the install, my guess has been I need to fix that. It's the "Large File Storage Not Configured". However, I've changed all the parameters it asks for. I have:

nginx:

- client_max_body_size 32

php.ini:

- post_max_size = 32
- memory_limit = -1 (disabled)
- max_input_vars = 200000
- upload_max_filesize = 32

I want it to use the default, to store things in MySQL, so I also have storage.mysql-engine.max-size at 8M.

But I also found this, that does not seem to be right:
`PhabricatorChunkedFileStorageEngine writable: No`
I have no idea how to change it though, or if I should.

The actual error message I get when I try to upload files (no matter what size) is:

> Upload Failure
>   Exception: No configured storage engine can store this file. See "Configuring File Storage" in the documentation for information on configuring storage engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from a Phacility staff member. It was just an error of mine, but they will update the documentation now to prevent more people from making that mistake - ´silverlining! :) https://secure.phabricator.com/D17037

I had `storage.mysql-engine.max-size 8`, as I thought that would give me 8MB. I've changed it to `8388608` now, which works, as it is supposed to be in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for anyone else.

In my case I am using, Engine: Local Disk, to store files but after configured it still gives error as mentioned below:

**Unhandled Exception ("PhutilAggregateException")**

```
  All storage engines failed to write file:
- PhabricatorLocalDiskFileStorageEngine: CommandException: Command failed with error #1!
  COMMAND
  mkdir -p /var/files/64/66
  
  STDOUT
  (empty)
  
  STDERR
  mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/files/64': Permission denied
```

As the error states that permission is denied so I got it working by assigning user to the dir and updating permissions.

- sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/files/
- sudo chmod 777 /var/files/